# matplotlib.yscale('log') generates empty plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am following an online lesson on using `matplotlib` with data frames.  The data frame is created from [this aapl.csv file](https://github.com/matplotlib/sample_data/raw/master/aapl.csv).  The essential steps from the lesson are:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
aapl = pd.read_csv( 'aapl.csv', index_col='date', parse_dates=True)
   # PLEASE UNCAPITALIZE COLUMN HEADINGS !!

aapl.head(6)
                 open    high     low   close    volume  adj close
   date                                                           
   2008-10-14  116.26  116.40  103.14  104.08  70749800     104.08
   2008-10-13  104.55  110.53  101.02  110.26  54967000     110.26
   2008-10-10   85.70  100.00   85.00   96.80  79260700      96.80
   2008-10-09   93.35   95.80   86.60   88.74  57763700      88.74
   2008-10-08   85.91   96.33   85.68   89.79  78847900      89.79
   2008-10-07  100.48  101.50   88.95   89.16  67099000      89.16

aapl.plot()       # Generates a plot

   <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x118afe048>

plt.yscale('log') # Generates a blank plot !
plt.show()        # Nothing happens !
```

According to examples in the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py), `yscale` should apply to a plot that was just plotted.

Can anyone suggest what might be the cause and/or troubleshooting measures?  I am using Spyder 3.3.2, installed on Windows 7 using Anaconda.

Comment: Instead do: `aapl.plot(logy=True)` Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#scales

Comment: If you run this code in a single cell of your notebook, or as a normal python script, it should work as expected.

Comment: @user2153235: Also, make sure you're running a recent version of matplotlib (3.1.1) and of pandas (0.25).

Comment: `aapl.plot(logy=True)` works, but the lesson is supposed to explore various code idioms, so I'm interested in why it doesn't work.  I'm running in a very locked down environment, so upgrading packages on the fly is not practical. However, `pkg_resources` shows that I have `matplotlib 3.0.2` and `pandas 0.23.4`. I'm working at the Spyder console rather than a notebook, but Saving the statements to a `*.py` file and executing with `runfile` does generate the correct plot.  Is this disparity characteristic of Spyder?